# Fatal Exception when trying to read PDF or ePub files in Android

Tags: android, file, pdf, epub

Previously I thought this may have been a PDFTextStream problem, so I tried a library designed to work with Android and I'm still receiving a Fatal Exception that restarts my app once I try to load my file with the library.

My previous question with the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388524/extracting-text-from-pdf-using-pdftextstream-on-android-yields-a-fatal-exception?noredirect=1#comment34038521_22388524

This time I tried an open-source library, ePubLib, and my app crashed on this line:

```
Book book = epubReader.readEpub(new FileInputStream(file));
```

where file =

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/burnett-secret-garden-illustrations.epub
```

There error was:

```
03-13 16:29:55.046: E/AndroidRuntime(17721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Please include any stack trace that followed that line of output in logcat.